# Rewrite rules for php urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've tried to find an answer for a question i had in my mind, but it seems to I can't find it.

How is it possible to make some php urls with "?" and "=" to /

Example one (1):

```
example.com/user.php?profile=example
```

to:

```
example.com/user/profile/example
```

Example two (2):

```
example.com/forum.php?thread=example-in-an-example
```

to:

```
example.com/forum/thread/example-in-an-example
```

Like a code that takes the second "/" (slash) as a "?" and the third and the rest as a "=" so i can freely use it instead of making a new one for each page...

LIKE: /forum (or any others) is like the page itself
AND: /thread (or any others) is like the $_GET
AND: /example-in-an-example (or any others) is like the value to the $_GET

EXTRA:
here is a code from Jeroen:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ $1.php?$2=$3 [L]
```

Problem one (1): when going to like: "example.com/forum" or "example.com/user" its giving a 404 error
Problem two (2): When using links like "example.com/forum/thread/test-thread/reply/2" it gives 404 error, (supose to loop with "&" and "=" after making the 1st real one so its enable to use more than one $_GET)

Comment: Are you using a controller? Can you modify your PHP code? Are you writing something from scratch? What is the URL seen into the user's browser address bar? The clean url or the url with the query string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user/profile/(.*)/$ user.php?profile=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^forum/thread/(.*)/$ /forum.php?thread=$1 [L]
```

Or a more generic version...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ $1.php?$2=$3 [L]
```

*Make sure Apache's [mod rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) is enabled!*

Answer (score 1):

If you have full access to the application and you can modify the code, I can submit you some trick I usually use for my REST utilities.

Put **AllowOverride All** inside your apache configuration to enable .htaccess file.
Assure to **LoadModule** your **mod_rewrite** module too.

Create a .htaccess file into your web server document root (your application path) and put this stuff inside:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Create a file called index.php and put this inside, this will be your controller:

```
<?
        // echo "REQUEST_URI: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "</br>\n";
        $controller = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        //print_r($controller);

        $resource = $controller[1];
        $operation = $controller[2];
        $operation_value = $controller[3];

        echo "Requested resource: $resource, opetation: $operation, value: $operation_value<br>\n";

        switch($resource) {
        case 'user':
                echo "User requested\n";
                //require_once("user.php");
                break;
        case 'forum':
                echo "Forum requested\n";
                //require_once("forum.php");
                break;
        /* add any other resource */
        default:
                echo "Requested page was not found.\n";
                break;
        }
?>
```

When the user call http://example.com/user/profile/ZeroXitreo the page will be renderer as:

```
Requested resource: user, opetation: profile, value: ZeroXitreo
User requested
```

When the user call http://example.com/forum/thread/example-in-an-example the page will be:

```
Requested resource: forum, opetation: thread, value: example-in-an-example
Forum requested
```

Read the PHP code of the controller, I think it's quite self explaining.